# How is the AKS primality test Rosetta code so simple?

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, primality-test

**Skip to the end to see alternative question.**

The following is a Python implementation of the [AKS Primality Test](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2004/160-2/p12).

```
from sympy import *

def expand_x_1(n): 
    # This version uses a generator and thus less computations
    c = 1
    for i in range(n//2 + 1):       # // means flooring after divide
        c = c*(n - i)//(i + 1)
        yield c

def aks(p):
    if p==2:
        return True

    for i in expand_x_1(p):
        if i % p:
            # we stop without computing all possible solutions
            return False
    return True


for n in range(2, 10000):
    primality = aks(n)
    primality1 = isprime(n)
    if primality != primality1:
        print("Fails @", n)  # Never prints
        assert (0)
    else:
        print(primality)
```

How is it possible that they took that much more in-depth pseudocode of the algorithm (that involves polynomial operations), and converted it into this 10-line version?

Is the above really the AKS primality test?  I got it from:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes#Python

---

Let the input be called $n$, not $p$.

The code in `expand_x_1(n)` must be computing:

$$c_0 = 1, c_i = \lfloor \dfrac{c_{i-1}(n-i)}{i + 1}\rfloor$$

Where $c_i = $ the $i$th yielded value.  The other code using this value simply tests whether $c_i \neq 0 \pmod n$, in which case (if true) it returns `False` for composite.  Else if for all $c_i$ values at $i = 0..\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1$ we have $c_i = 0 \pmod n$, then `True` is returned.

The recursion plus this test don't seem at all like what makes up the AKS algorithm.  So I was hoping an analytic number theorist could explain the formula.

### **Alternatively, if you can't answer the above, then:**

How can we study the formula for $c_i$; can you think of any rearrangments it has? Such as maybe the denominators combining across recursive subcalls that have floor etc.

This is so I don't have to open up another question regarding this formula.

---

For example, I modified the code to:

```
def expand_x_1(n): 
   c = 1
   d = 1
   for i in range(n//2 + 1):
       d *= (i + 1)
       c = c*(n - i)
       yield c//d
```

Therefore, since it's getting no failures when I run it, I can somewhat safely assume that "denominators can be combined" algebraically, i.e. there is some
identity made use of that derives from the [basic properties of floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

What else can we say and how does this formula relate to polynomial arithmetic?

Comment: there is a readable article by Granville... https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/S0273-0979-04-01037-7.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy I would have to really study that paper and maybe then have a chance of reasoning why the above code formula works.  It looks like the recursion: $c_0 = 1, c_i = \lfloor \dfrac{c_{i-1}(n-i)}{i + 1}\rfloor$ and that isn't mentioned anywhere in AKS papers including Granville's.  Where $c_i =$ the $i$th yield of `expand_x_1(n)`.  A yield simply returns a value (internally handled as a generator object in Python), without completely returning from the function.

Comment: Maybe the guys over on code golf can get it even shorter.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I don't think it's possible.  Look at the formula!  How could that be reduced without heavy algebra, hence MSE is the place ask.

Comment: The title of this Rosetta Code wiki page is just totally wrong. This isn’t the AKS algorithm. See https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Talk:AKS_test_for_primes#This_isn.27t_AKS.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg what test is this then?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder It is Lemma 2.1 from the v6 paper, which was known hundreds of years ago to many mathematicians.  Its performance is worse than naive trial division.  The authors of AKS reference it, indicate why it is computationally useless as is, then discuss what could make it useful, then proceed to show how it can be done.  Most of the paper is carefully showing exactly how the limiting is done and why this leads to the desired polynomial complexity.  BTW, even after all improvements, it is still not as fast in practice as APRCL and ECPP, but is a landmark work in the theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers you’ve labelled as $c_i$ are the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula) $\binom ni$; the code checks whether $\binom ni \equiv 0 \pmod n$ for all $0 < i \le \frac n2$.  **This is [not the AKS algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Talk:AKS_test_for_primes#This_isn.27t_AKS).**  It’s the exponential-time brute force algorithm listed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Concepts) to *motivate* the AKS algorithm.